# Increment value when code exists

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a MySQL table with 2 columns, in the first one is an IP adress and in the second one is a integer which should be incremented.

When a new IP visits the website, integer corresponding to that IP should be incremented by 1.
The PHP scrip should also handle the case when IP address is already present in database.

This is for updating the integer:

```
UPDATE user SET points = points + 1 WHERE code = '$u'
```

And this is for adding a new ip to the database (I use the attribute "unique" that no double values could be saved):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO $DB_Table (ip,code) values(INET_ATON('$ip'),'$code')
```

Now I want that the integer is incremented by 1 only when a new IP visits the website. It would be great if the I can reduce the two queries and get the job done in 1 query. Thank you for any help.

Comment: You first check if the IP exist inside the table. IF not, you INSERT. If so, you UPDATE.

Comment: use php to check if the IP exist and update the count.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INSERT INTO $DB_Table (ip,code) values(INET_ATON('$ip'),'$code') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE user SET points = points + 1 WHERE code = '$u'`

In the MYSQL table have the `points` DEFAULT = 1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use something like this

```
INSERT INTO table (ip, code, points) values ('ip value', 'code value', 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE points = points + 1 WHERE ip = 'ip value';
```

Note that you would need a primary key or unique index on ip for this to work.  I am not sure what the 'code' value represents so that could actually be problematic for the update clause if it is also a unique key.

Note that I added an initial value of 1 for points in the insert clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the two together by using the [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) method:

```
INSERT INTO visitors (ip, code, counter) VALUES (INET_ATON($ip), '$code', 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE counter = counter + 1;
```